# React-Native whole list deleting instead of selected item

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I have a somewhat todo list interface involving a shopping list which lets the user enter an item and the each item is displayed using a ScrollView being mapped  by Array.map() however when I select on an individual item to be deleted the entire list deletes. I can't seem to find the problem as each individual key prop is unique.

The code:

```
    let j = 1
    const [ingriList, setIngriList] = useState([])
    const [ingri, setIngri] = useState('')
    
    const deleteItem = (key) => {
        const filteredItems = ingriList.filter(item => item.key !== key)
        setIngriList(filteredItems)
    }
    
    const handleSubmit = () => {
        return (
            setIngri(''),
            ingri.length === 0
                ? <Text/>
                : setIngriList(ingriList.concat(ingri))
        )
    }
    
    return(
        <View style = { styles.ingriContainer }>
            <View style={styles.addPhotoCont}>
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.textInput}
                    placeholder={'Add Something'}
                    onChangeText={item => setIngri(item)}
                    value={ingri}
                />
            </View>
                <View>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleSubmit}>
                        <Text style={styles.addButton}>Add</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            <ScrollView>
                {ingriList.map(i =>
                    (
                        <View key={j++}>
                            <Text style={styles.ingridientValues}>{i}</Text>
                            <View style={styles.cancel}>
                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => deleteItem(ingriList.key)}>
                                    <MaterialIcons name="cancel" size={30} color={Colors.orange} />
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    )
                )
                }
            </ScrollView>
        </View >
    )
```

I would really appreciate it from the bottom of my heart if someone could help me with figuring out why the entire list is being deleted instead of the selected item. Thank you in advance!!!!!

Comment: Place a break point on the first line of the deleteItem line. I get the felling that your key value is not what you expect.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Where are you declaring the variable j? For the key on the ScrollView? Did you intend to use i++?

Comment: To debug react-native code read [this](https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging.html) or [this if you are using VSC](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/reactjs-tutorial)

Comment: I declared it above the useState() hook

Comment: Is `ingriList` a list of strings or a list of objects? It seems like you are adding strings to it and then expecting each element to have a `key` attribute.

Comment: yeah ingriList is a list of strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `ingriList` is a list of strings, since you are calling `setIngriList` as follows:

```
setIngriList(ingriList.concat(ingri))
```

Now when you attempt to delete an item from this list, you call `deleteItem(ingriList.key)`, but `ingriList.key` is `undefined`. Finally, in `deleteItem`, you are filtering out entries that match the key attribute, but since the `key` attribute is `undefined` for each element, all of the entries match and `ingriList` is set to an empty array. This is most likely why you observe that all elements are deleted.

Try keeping a unique identifier for each 'ingri' in your `ingriList`, by making it a list of objects instead:

```
const handleSubmit = (ingriId, ingri) => {
  const newIngriList = ingriList.concat({ id: ingriId, val: ingri })
  setIngriList(newIngriList)
}

const deleteItem = (ingriId) => {
  setIngriList(ingriList.filter(ingri => ingri.id !== ingriId))
}
```

Each entry in your `ingriList` needs to have a unique `id` attribute that you can them pass to the `deleteItem` function that will then remove it from the array.

Comment: Thank you soooo sooo much . Your detailed explanation really made so much sense and solved the problem I was having . Thank you . Have an excellent rest of the day !!!!!